# Read and rewrite specific parts of a text file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I have a text file that I want to read

```
-------------------
dog: bred
gender: male
age: 6
birth: july
extra:
-purebreed
PRICE: list price 
--------------------
dog: bred
gender: female
age: 10
birth: march
extra:
-purebreed
PRICE: list price 
--------------------
dog: bred
gender: male
age: 2
birth: November 
extra:
-purebreed
PRICE: list price 
--------------------
```

I have read different ways to do this but when I am trying it doesn't seem to work. I need to rewrite the file with the dashes and only the dog: and age: information. I have a lot of entries and I need to be able to only list of the dog and age of each with the dashes to separate each listing. Would I need to split based on the colon or how do I only pick out the dog and age?

Comment: What did you try yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might be what you're looking for. What I do is I read in the text file into a list (one line for each element in the list). Then iterate through the newly created list, if the dog, age, or dashes are in that line, it then writes it to the new text file. If the line doesn't match any of that criteria, it doesn't worry about it.

```
dogFile = open('dogs.txt', 'r')
lines = dogFile.readlines()
dogFile.close()

newDogFile = open('newDogs.txt', 'w')
for line in lines:
    if 'dog:' in line or 'age:' in line or '--------------------' in line:
        newDogFile.write(line)
newDogFile.close()
```

Whichever way you think looks nicer, doesn't matter, the outcome is the same for each method, which is:

```
dog: bred
age: 6
--------------------
dog: bred
age: 10
--------------------
dog: bred
age: 2
--------------------
```

Comment: Why not condense it to `if 'dog:' in line or 'age:' in line or '-------' in line: newDogFile.write(line)`?

Comment: would there be a way to include "dog:" and "age:" before the outcomes?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know you wanted that, hold on @user3822682

Comment: @user3822682 please see revised answer

Answer (score 0):

The following code writes to a new text file, as it reads in from the old text file.

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(["a.txt"], inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    if 'dog' in line or 'age' in line or '-------' in line:        
        sys.stdout.write(line)

#output

-------------------
dog: bred
age: 6
--------------------
dog: bred
age: 10
--------------------
dog: bred
age: 2
--------------------
```